# javascript class method encapsulation issue

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new with javascript and I think this is a dumb question but I don't know how to search my issue on google.

I have a "class" like that :

```
function Myclass(){}

Myclass.prototype.method1() = function(){

    whatever.onload = function(){
      this.method2();
    }

};

Myclass.prototype.method2() = function(){};
```

My problem is that "this" isn't related to my class anymore. In this anonymous function scope, I can't reach my method2.

How can I solve this issue ?

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is like this:

```
Myclass.prototype.method1 = function(){
    var self = this;
    whatever.onload = function(){
      self.method2();
    }
};
```

The variable `self` remains in existence even after `method1` finishes executing such that the onload function declared with `method1` can still access it later. (For more information about this, google "JavaScript closures".)

Comment: I think you meant `Myclass.prototype.method1 = function(){` in your first line of code. Looks like a typo.

Comment: @Reno - Yep. I had copied that line directly from the question and didn't notice the problem. Fixed.